# Locate the setup log file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have retrieved a message after completing installing SharePoint 2013 that says

> One or more required office components failed to complete
>   successfully. For more information, consult the setup log file.

Where can I find the setup log file in Windows Server 2012?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> If Setup fails, check log files in the Temp folder of the user account that you used to run Setup. Ensure that you are logged in using the same user account, and then type %temp% in the location bar in Windows Explorer. If the path in Windows Explorer resolves to a location that ends in a "1" or "2", you will have to navigate up one level to view the log files. The log file name is SharePoint Server Setup (<Time stamp>).

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263202.aspx#section4